# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} {n \choose k}{n-k \choose \lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor} = {2n+1 \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

The problem is the following: prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} {n \choose k}{n-k \choose \lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor} = {2n+1 \choose n}$

I was trying to prove some concrete combinatorial examples to make the LHS equivalent to $2n+1 \choose n$.

We choose $k$ in the first $n$ items, but I am not sure how to map $2^{k} {n-k \choose \lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor}$ to choosing $n-k$ elements from $n+1$ items

[EDIT] This might help. [Combinatorial proof $\sum_i^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (-1)^i {n-i\choose i} 2^{n-2i} = n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191297/combinatorial-proof-sum-i-lfloorn-2-rfloor-1i-n-i-choose-i-2n-2i?rq=1)

Comment: Are the brackets supposed to be a floor function?

Comment: @Gabe yes, it's a floor function

Comment: Plugging in n=3 the LHS evaluates to 3 + 18 + 12 + 8 = 41 and the RHS evaluates to 35 I think.

Comment: @Gabe sorry I had a typo, I corrected the orignal question. apologies ...

Comment: Note that $2^{k} {n-k \choose \lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor}\ne \binom{n+1}{n-k}$ in general; for example set $n=4$, $k=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k {n\choose k}
{n-k\choose \lfloor \frac{n-k}{2} \rfloor}
= \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{n-k} {n\choose k}
{k\choose \lfloor k/2 \rfloor}
\\ =
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k} {n\choose 2k}
{2k\choose k}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k-1} {n\choose 2k+1}
{2k+1\choose k}.$$

Now for the first sum we write

$${n\choose 2k} {2k\choose k} =
\frac{n!}{(n-2k)! \times k! \times k!} =
{n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k}.$$

We obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k}
{n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k}
{n\choose k} [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k}
{n\choose k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}.$$

Now  the coefficient  extractor enforces  the  sum limits  and we  may
continue with

$$2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{-2k}
{n\choose k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}
\\ = 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n} [z^n] (z+2)^{2n}
= \frac{1}{2^n} {2n\choose n} 2^n = {2n\choose n}.$$

For the second sum we write

$${n\choose 2k+1} {2k+1\choose k} =
\frac{n!}{(n-2k-1)! \times k! \times (k+1)!} =
{n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k-1}.$$

We obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k-1}
{n\choose k} {n-k\choose n-2k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k-1}
{n\choose k} [z^{n-2k-1}] (1+z)^{n-k}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} 2^{n-2k-1}
{n\choose k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}.$$

Once more the coefficient extractor enforces the sum limits and we may
continue with

$$2^{n-1} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{-2k}
{n\choose k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}
\\ = 2^{n-1} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} [z^{n-1}] (z+2)^{2n}
= \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} {2n\choose n-1} 2^{n+1} = {2n\choose n-1}.$$

Collecting everything we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{2n\choose n} + {2n\choose n-1} = {2n+1\choose n}.}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate the step when you introduce $z$? wasn't familiar with that

Comment: [Wikipedia on formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) has additional information.

Comment: Can you elaborate this step? I read about formal series but still not very sure how this step follows: 

$$2^{n-1} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{-2k}
{n\choose k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}
\\ = 2^{n-1} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} [z^{n-1}] (z+2)^{2n}
= \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} {2n\choose n-1} 2^{n+1} = {2n\choose n-1}.$$

Comment: In going from (1) to (2) we use the binomial theorem. From (2) to (3) we first simplify the rational function that appears, then cancel the common term $(1+z)^n$ and collect powers of two. The third line is a routine coefficient extraction from the power $(z+2)^{2n}.$

Comment: Thanks, I think one last question -- forgive me if it;'s a basic question:
how are you able to write ${n-k \choose n-2k} = z^{n-2k} (1+z)^{n-k}$?

Comment: You need to be careful not to omit the parenthesis on the coefficient extractor, what we have here is not multiplication. Write $[z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k}.$ The identity holds because $$[z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k} = [z^{n-2k}] \left({n-k\choose 0}z^0 + {n-k\choose 1}z^1 + \cdots + {n-k\choose n-2k} z^{n-2k}+\cdots\right) = {n-k\choose n-2k}.$$  In general $[z^k] (1+z)^n = {n\choose k}.$